# GitHub AcademicPages cannot add new pages

Tags: git, github

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question. If it's not, I'll happily take it down.

I'm using [AcademicPages](https://academicpages.github.io/), a fork of Minimal mistakes. I want to add a new page to my website, so the first thing I do is navigate to `_pages` and create a new file, let's call it `research.md`. I add the following code:

```
---
permalink: /research/
title: "Research"
---
```

and then add some content. Next, I go to `_data > navigation.yml` and change my directory to include the new page:

```
main:
    - title: "Research"
    url: /research/

    - title: "CV"
    url: /cv/ 

   - title: "Contact"
    url: /contact/
```

For the two pages that already exist, CV and Contact, this works fine. But whenever I try to add a new page using the same setup, my site fails to publish and I'm given the error "github-pages can't satisfy your Gemfile's dependencies." Any idea how to fix this?

If it helps, I am following [Jay Rob Williams' tutorial](https://jayrobwilliams.com/posts/2020/08/website-content/), and I have not added anything to my code that he doesn't explicitly recommend.

Comment: Odds are you aren't going to get a lot of help on Stackoverflow; however, since the project is active again you might want to try asking over in the [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io/discussions)